# Update same rows simultaneously different columns. DeadLock

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

In my Javascript code I call 3 simultaneos WebMethods.

**WebMethod 1**

```
UPDATE MyTable
    SET ColA = 'Val1'
WHERE Condition1 = 'X'
AND Condition2 = 'Y'
```

**WebMethod 2**

```
UPDATE MyTable
    SET ColB = 'Val2'
WHERE Condition1 = 'X'
AND Condition2 = 'Y'
```

**WebMethod 3**

```
UPDATE MyTable
    SET ColC = 'Val3'
WHERE Condition1 = 'X'
AND Condition2 = 'Y'
```

**MyTable**

[image]

As expected I'm getting DeadLock, even if i use `WITH (ROWLOCK)` in the update statement

[image]

How can I tell SqlServer to lock the rows but allow other update to read.

because the DeadLock disappear when:

```
UPDATE MyTable
    SET ColA = 'Val1'
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM MyTable WITH(READUNCOMMITTED)
    WHERE Condition1 = 'X'
    AND Condition2 = 'Y'
)
```

Comment: One might ask why you are calling 3 methods to update different columns of the same row at the same time. Seems like a single update would make far more sense. Or is this just an example of real world locking?

Comment: Its just an example, cause in real world, i have multiple users updating the same column, not the same javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The 'lazy' and way best not to do this (understand the reasons why it can be bad!) would be to add `WITH(NOLOCK)` to your `SELECT` statements:

```
SELECT ID
FROM MyTable WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE Condition1 = 'X'
AND Condition2 = 'Y'
```

`NOLOCK` can result in dirty reads, and incomplete data being returned.  A much better option is to use `READPAST`, it all depends on what you are trying to do.

Ideally you'd want to just have the updates all run with 1 statement but perhaps it's just that you have made a simple example :)  It's throwing a deadlock for a good reason, you could just make each call sequentially.

If you want to do the SQL without a `SELECT` you could try doing `UPDATE MyTable WITH (ROWLOCK)` but remember that it is just a hint, there is no guarantee.

Comment: NOLOCK is a terrible way to deal with this. And as part of an update it can do really awesome things like corrupt indexes. Please don't suggest that people use NOLOCK for this type of thing. They may not know better and actually follow your advice. For some more in depth reading on the "features" of NOLOCK take a look here. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: I'm well aware of the danger, hence the warning.  I don't think I'd use it for production code.  I probably should emphasize the danger more.

Comment: I'm aware of the danger of using NOLOCK. And If I use WITH (ROWLOCK) the deadlock still apears. Always.

Comment: Well...knowing the real dangers perhaps not suggesting using a dangerous approach would be more prudent. ;) But maybe you are only referring to other select statements, not the update in which case it is a somewhat common (albeit not without issue) to circumvent locking.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to find if table is lock then do thing accordingly.

```
if not exists(SELECT
OBJECT_NAME(p.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
resource_type, resource_description
FROM
sys.dm_tran_locks l
JOIN sys.partitions p ON l.resource_associated_entity_id = p.hobt_id
where OBJECT_NAME(p.OBJECT_ID)='MyTable')
Begin

Update Sql
End
else
begin
-- Table is lock
insert the info in another table.

Later run any Job and update the table.
end
```

Another way,

Handle concurrency issue in Ajax itself.

[AjaxQueue1](https://gist.github.com/OllieTerrance/158a4c436baa64c4324803467844b00f)  [AjaxQueue2](https://gist.github.com/pavelmaca/942485)

So google something similar.